# Invalid characters Arduino, Bluetooth (HM10 ) and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-ide

I am having an issue trying to send commands to my Arduino Mega from my Android  Xamarin.Forms app. When i use Bluetooth terminal app from play store it works, but my code does not. In the Arduino terminal i am just getting squares as if it is a baud rate issue or something. but from what i can see the baud rate is always determined by the device, which defaults to 9600 for the HM10.

I am using this library for the bluetooth https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

**Arduino Sketch (works with bt terminal app)**

```
void loop()
{
    // Read from the Bluetooth module and send to the Arduino Serial Monitor
    if (Serial3.available())
    {
        byte y = Serial3.read();
         //int x = (int)y;
        Serial.write(y);
    }


    // Read from the Serial Monitor and send to the Bluetooth module
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        c = Serial.read();

        // do not send line end characters to the HM-10
        if (c != 10 & c != 13)
        {
            Serial3.write(c);
        }

        // Echo the user input to the main window. 
        // If there is a new line print the ">" character.
        if (NL) { Serial.print("\r\n>"); NL = false; }
            Serial.write(c);
        if (c == 10) { NL = true; }
    }
}
```

**Then my send code in my Xamarin.Forms app**

```
    private async Task Button_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_charataristice != null &&  _charataristice.CanWrite)
        {
            var data = Convert.ToByte(16);
            _charataristice.WriteType = CharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse;
            await _charataristice.WriteAsync(new[] { data });
        }

    }
```

Would appreciate any help, the value i am trying to revive is alwasy a number and should fall within one byte.

Comment: You are sending a hard-coded value of 16(dec) or 0x10 hex, so a DLE ? What do you except to be displayed for that value?

Comment: @SushiHangover I am expecting to receive the number 16

Comment: Then take the decimal 16 that you are getting in that received "byte", and convert it to a string in order to "print".

Comment: @SushiHangover such a simple fix! Thank you , if you post it as an answer ill tick it.

Comment: Add the code that you ended up in a self-answer so future SO searchers can see what you used ;-)